# Newsletter for product catalog

Tags: postmaster, mailinglist, newsletter

My client want to send a newsletter with a product's catalog to his customers

Is it possible with Postmaster? I thought that I need to create a template with custom fields, then the clients publish entries and use "comunicate" to send the newsletter

I don't know if it's possible or is the right way, 'cause I never developed a site with this functionality

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please could you provide more information about what the newsletter would include? Would it be the entire catalogue, or just the most recent addition? Would it be sent when a customer requests it, a one-off when the site administrator sees fit, or a recurring (weekly/monthly) thing?

Comment: Hi andrew, in order:
- Most recent addition
- A one-off when the site administrator sees fit

Answer (score 5):

I would encourage the client to use a third party service such as CampaignMonitor or MailChimp. This will give you more reliable deliverability, excellent reporting and list management, as well as safeguarding your domain name against ISP blacklisting for unsolicited spam.

You can then integrate these services with EE. For example, something I've done before is to create an 'emails' EE channel and use relationship fields to pull in various articles and news items into an html email web page, complete with all the necessary CampaignMonitor tags for dynamic salutations, unsubscribe links and all the legal stuff that you are required to put on such mailings. CampaignMonitor then allows you to import the email directly from the web page.

I believe there are some ways you can integrate these services more tightly, but I've found this to be sufficient for my needs.

Comment: I second this approach. Third party services will cost a little for every campaing send but the service they offer outweighs the cost. Also I would ask the customer if the content creation will really have to be dynamic as these services offer a great and easy way to add content (pictures, too). Just as always: try to make it fit for the clients needs, this stuff can get complex quickly (= expensive).